# Prepopulating selected values from JSON for multiple select using Knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I'm trying to populate which options have been selected, for any given multiple select, based on the json presented. It seems to be working fine if I only choose one select option, but if I choose multiple I get no result. Also, I'm trying to show the selected option(s) in a text beneath the multi select, but that doesn't seem be be working if I change the option chosen.

I know I'm close as I'm not getting any errors... so what am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

**Knockout**

```
var OptionsModel = function(options) {
var self = this;
self.options = ko.observableArray(options);
self.allFacilityCodes = ko.observable("");
self.facilityCode = ko.observable("");

self.selectedFacilityCode = ko.observable();

self.addOption = function() {
    self.options.push({
        facilityCode: ["A116", "A118", "A120", "A122", "A124", "A125", "A126", "A127", "A128", "A130", "A132", "A134", "A138", "A139", "A140", "A142", "A143", "A144", "A146", "A148", "A152", "A154", "A270", "A364", "A365", "A366", "A370"],
        accountType: "",
        customCode: "",
        facilityPT: "",
        selectedFacilityCode: ""
    });
};

self.removeOption = function(option) {
    self.options.remove(option);
};

self.save = function(form) {
    alert("Could now transmit to server: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.options));
    // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.options);
};
};

var viewModel = new OptionsModel([
{ facilityCode: ["A116", "A118", "A120", "A122", "A124", "A125", "A126", "A127", "A128", "A130", "A132", "A134", "A138", "A139", "A140", "A142", "A143", "A144", "A146", "A148", "A152", "A154", "A270", "A364", "A365", "A366", "A370"],
selectedFacilityCode: ["A116", "A125", "A127"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"},
{ facilityCode: ["A116", "A118", "A120", "A122", "A124", "A125", "A126", "A127", "A128", "A130", "A132", "A134", "A138", "A139", "A140", "A142", "A143", "A144", "A146", "A148", "A152", "A154", "A270", "A364", "A365", "A366", "A370"], 
selectedFacilityCode: ["A270"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"},
{ facilityCode: ["A116", "A118", "A120", "A122", "A124", "A125", "A126", "A127", "A128", "A130", "A132", "A134", "A138", "A139", "A140", "A142", "A143", "A144", "A146", "A148", "A152", "A154", "A270", "A364", "A365", "A366", "A370"], 
selectedFacilityCode: ["A139", "A140", "A148"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"},
{ facilityCode: ["A116", "A118", "A120", "A122", "A124", "A125", "A126", "A127", "A128", "A130", "A132", "A134", "A138", "A139", "A140", "A142", "A143", "A144", "A146", "A148", "A152", "A154", "A270", "A364", "A365", "A366", "A370"],    
selectedFacilityCode: ["A148"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"},
{ facilityCode: ["A116", "A118", "A120", "A122", "A124", "A125", "A126", "A127", "A128", "A130", "A132", "A134", "A138", "A139", "A140", "A142", "A143", "A144", "A146", "A148", "A152", "A154", "A270", "A364", "A365", "A366", "A370"],
    selectedFacilityCode: ["A130"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"}
]);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

// Activate jQuery Validation
$("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/oc9oohoh/7/

Any help would be great!

thanks
Joe

Comment: Try `selectedOptions` instead of `value` binding for multiple select. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html

Comment: okay, great! That fixed the selections on load: http://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/oc9oohoh/8/

Comment: why isn't it updating though when I choose new options?

Comment: When bound variables don't update, it's usually because they are not `observable`s. That seems to be the case with `selectedFacilityCode`

Answer (score 1):

Alright check it out, I think I got what you were looking for, minus validation.

Main problems I saw were that you really wanted instances of Options rather than just one big thing. Also it looked like the facilityCode just repeated over and over so I set it to a literal in the OptionModel.facilityCode observable.

Brought the click function up to the root viewModel. Created a "data" array for everything else and mapped it in to self.options observableArray in the viewModel. Had to modify some of the html a little bit, but I think that should get you going.

```
var model;
var data = [
    { selectedFacilityCode: ["A116", "A125", "A127"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"},
    { selectedFacilityCode: ["A270"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"},
    { selectedFacilityCode: ["A139", "A140", "A148"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"},
    { selectedFacilityCode: ["A148"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"},
    { selectedFacilityCode: ["A130"], accountType: "Account Type text goes here", customCode: "Custom Code text goes here", facilityPT: "0"}
];

var OptionsModel = function(options) {
    var self = this;

    self.facilityCode = ko.observable(["A116", "A118", "A120", "A122", "A124", "A125", "A126", "A127", "A128", "A130", "A132", "A134", "A138", "A139", "A140", "A142", "A143", "A144", "A146", "A148", "A152", "A154", "A270", "A364", "A365", "A366", "A370"]);
    self.accountType = ko.observable(options.accountType);
    self.customCode = ko.observable(options.customCode);
    self.facilityPT = ko.observable(options.facilityPT);

    self.selectedFacilityCode = ko.observable();

};

var viewModel = function (definition) {
    var self = this;

  // Create an observableArray, using var data to store instances of OptionsModel
  self.options = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(definition, function(item) {
    return new OptionsModel(item);
  }));

  // Remove selected option
  self.removeOption = function(option) {
    self.options.remove(option);
  };

  // Add new option, could be extended with a small form instead of object literal
  // Form fields will still work, whatever you fill out will show when you hit submit
  self.addOption = function () {
    var emptyOption = {
      accountType: '',
      customCode: '',
      facilityCode: '',
    }
    self.options.push(new OptionsModel(emptyOption));
  }

  // Alert options observable array
  self.save = function(form) {
        alert("Could not transmit to server: " + ko.toJSON(self.options));
        // To actually transmit to server as a regular form post, write this: ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.options);
    };
};

model = new viewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(model);

// Activate jQuery Validation
$("form").validate({ submitHandler: viewModel.save });
```

[jsfiddle.net/oc9oohoh/22/](http://jsfiddle.net/oc9oohoh/22/)

Comment: Hey Budhead! Thanks a bunch!! Works exactly how I envisioned! I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: @Bedhead2004 one other comment... Is there a way to add a space after the selectedFacilityCode results? so instead of "A116,A125,A127" the result would be "A116, A125, A127". Seems like if I have several results they're not wrapping as it renders as one long string. Let me know. thanks again!

Comment: Change self.selectedFacilityCode to ko.observableArray();
    
Add this...

1self.selectedCodeMaster = ko.computed(function () {
     return self.selectedFacilityCode().map(function(code){
       return " " + code ;
      });` and assign selectedCodeMaster or whatever you end up naming it in the html

Comment: Like this? Sorry I keep editing this lol. There is probably a cleaner way to do it though...

http://jsfiddle.net/oc9oohoh/26/

Comment: sorry man, one last thing... why aren't the selectedOptions showing on load? once you select them, they get populated. On load though, the multiple selects aren't selected, and the selected options text isn't present.   Here's another option I was working on prior to your response: https://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/oc9oohoh/11/

Comment: ironically in the link I sent above, it works great on load, but if you choose edit to toggle the row and change the select menus or inputs, they don't get updated

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oc9oohoh/40/

Check this out, I think this is doing what you'd like... Let me know if you need help understanding it. I'm just assuming since you made it this far you have a basic understanding.

Comment: Here's a more polished example. Doesn't use as much "hacky" css stuff because it relies mroe on bootstrap's stuff. http://jsfiddle.net/oc9oohoh/53/